# How to draw a random sample from a normal distribution withing a range with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics

I am not sure how to specify two arguments for the np.random.normal function:

1. I want the min=10 and max=100

How do I add this to this code?

```
np.random.normal(size = 100, loc = 68.32, scale = 25.7)
```

Comment: The easiest thing is probably to draw many samples and discard those which are out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you limit the minimum and maximum, the data will no longer be normally distributed. That's why it doesn't make sense for `normal` to support such arguments.

If you want to pick numbers from normal distribution and subsequently limit to an interval, use something like:

```
data = np.random.normal(size=1000, loc=68.32, scale=25.7)
data_lim = data[np.where(np.logical_and(data > 10, data < 100))]
```

If you want numbers from an uniform distribution (which is naturally limited to a certain interval), see `np.random.rand`